# Error undefined reference to `boost::random::random_device::random_device()' when running using waf in ns3

Tags: c++, random, boost, ns-3

When I run the following code using g++ compiler it runs just fine. 
Then when I try running it using waf in ns3 it gives me the following error

```
challenge.cc:(.text.startup+0xc): undefined reference to 
`boost::random::random_device::random_device()'
```

This is the code,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/random.hpp>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>

int main()

{

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

using namespace boost::random;

boost::random::random_device seeder;

boost::random::mt19937 rng(seeder());



typedef independent_bits_engine<mt19937, 512, uint512_t> generator512_type;

generator512_type gen512(rng);



uint512_t challenge;

challenge = gen512();



std::cout << "The challenge is: " << challenge << std::endl;



    return 0;

     }
```

any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: Are you linking against Boost's random library?

Comment: Is there any reason you’re using boost::random::random_device instead of the std::random_device?

Comment: Are you linking against Boost's random library? I'm trying to use this library in my code 
Is there any reason you’re using boost::random::random_device instead of the std::random_device? I want to create a unique random value that's why I'm using boost::random